# WCF metadata missing operations

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, metadata

I have a simple webservice running in Visual Studio. If I attempt to view the metadata it is missing information about the operation and so svcutil generates client code without any methods. Is there anything wrong with my setup?

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="FCRPublishSOAP" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="Test.Publish.FCRPublish" behaviorConfiguration="SimpleServiceBehavior">
            <endpoint address="FCRPublish" behaviorConfiguration="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="FCRPublishSOAP" contract="IFCRPublish"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
    </services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SimpleServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" policyVersion="Policy15" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Interface:

```
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://Test/Publish", ConfigurationName="IFCRPublish")]
public interface IFCRPublish
{

    // CODEGEN: Generating message contract since the operation PublishNotification is neither RPC nor document wrapped.
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://Test/PublishNotification", ReplyAction="*")]
    PublishNotificationResponse1 PublishNotification(PublishNotificationRequest1 request);
}
```

Response:

```
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
public partial class PublishNotificationResponse1
{

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://Test/PublishTypes", Order=0)]
    public PublishNotificationResponse PublishNotificationResponse;

    public PublishNotificationResponse1()
    {
    }

    public PublishNotificationResponse1(PublishNotificationResponse PublishNotificationResponse)
    {
        this.PublishNotificationResponse = PublishNotificationResponse;
    }
}
```

Request:

```
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
public partial class PublishNotificationRequest1
{

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://Test/PublishTypes", Order=0)]
    public PublishNotification PublishNotification;

    public PublishNotificationRequest1()
    {
    }

    public PublishNotificationRequest1(PublishNotification PublishNotification)
    {
        this.PublishNotification = PublishNotification;
    }
}
```

This is the metadata I receive:

```
<wsdl:import namespace="http://Test/Publish" location="http://localhost:3992/FCRPublish.svc?wsdl=wsdl0"/>
<wsdl:types/>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFCRPublish" type="i0:IFCRPublish">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="FCRPublish">
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IFCRPublish" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IFCRPublish">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:3992/FCRPublish.svc"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Where has my operation gone?

Comment: Does `PublishNotificationResponse1` have a `DataContract` attribute?

Comment: No but it has a MessageContract attribute. I will edit the post to include the request and response objects.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Worked it out. Setting ReplyAction="*" for an OperationContract means the WsdlExporter (which publishes the metadata) will ignore that Operation. Setting any other value fixes it.

What bothers me about this is that svcutil will by default set replyaction to * which means svcutil by default creates services for which the metadata is effectively broken.

Comment: Great work in finding this. Thanks a ton.  I am working with WCSF Blue tool for client creation also.

Comment: I've just come across this as well ... there has to be a reason why, this has just wasted an afternoon for me.

Answer (score 0):

try removing `FCRPublish` from the address of your enpoint... your mex endpoint is there and seems ok, so I believe it should work

Comment: taking a closer look to your code, I never added a `MessageBodyMemberAttribute` without a `MessageHeaderAttribute` , could you add one just in case?