# WCF ReplyAction="*" breaks metadata

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, metadata

The following contract does not generate an operation in the metadata, yet If I remove the reply action or set it to "" the metadata now generates the operation correctly. Why?

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://Test/Publish", ConfigurationName="IFCRPublish")]
public interface IFCRPublish
{

    // CODEGEN: Generating message contract since the operation PublishNotification is neither RPC nor document wrapped.
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://Test/PublishNotification", ReplyAction="*")]
    PublishNotificationResponse1 PublishNotification(PublishNotificationRequest1 request);
}
```

The full service code is in [WCF metadata missing operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214815/wcf-metadata-missing-operations) if it is required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting ReplyAction="*" for an OperationContract means the WsdlExporter (which publishes the metadata) will ignore that Operation. Setting any other value will fix it.

Comment: you could also just remove the attribute completely and that should still work.