# Why fetching URL with ?wsdl suffix produces wsdl with no operation info?

Tags: web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

I have WCF WS running as Console application and the operation info is missing when wsdl is fetched with web browser http://localhost:7903/MyService/?wsdl

Why is that? Is the fetched wsdl below useful anyway?

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/"xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex"xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:i0="http://www.mycompany.com/nis/MyService/wsdl/v1.0"xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" name="ptMyService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:import namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/nis/MyService/wsdl/v1.0" location="http://0.0.0.0:7903/MyService/?wsdl=wsdl0"/>
<wsdl:types/>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IptMyService" type="i0:IptMyService">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="ptMyService">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IptMyService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IptMyService">
<soap:address location="http://0.0.0.0:7903/MyService/"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The actual WSDL looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions
  xmlns:cmp="http://www.mycompany.com/nis/MyService/v1.0"
  xmlns:msgs="http://www.mycompany.com/nis/MyServicemessages/v1.0"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:tns="http://www.mycompany.com/nis/MyService/wsdl/v1.0"
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
  xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
  targetNamespace="http://www.mycompany.com/nis/MyService/wsdl/v1.0"
  name="MyServiceService"
  xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

  <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
  <types>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="mycompany.nis.MyServicemessages.xsd" namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/nis/MyServicemessages/v1.0" />
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="mycompany.nis.MyService.xsd" namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/nis/MyService/v1.0" />
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>


  <message name="mMyService">
    <part name="parameters" element="msgs:components" />
  </message>
  <message name="mMyServiceResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="msgs:syncresult" />
  </message>
  <message name="GetComponentRequest">
    <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
    <part name="parameters" element="msgs:GetComponent" />
  </message>
  <message name="GetComponentResponse">
    <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
    <part name="parameters" element="msgs:GetComponentResponse" />
  </message>
  <message name="RequestHeaderMessage">
    <part name="RequestHeaderPart" element="msgs:RequestHeader" />
  </message>
  <message name="ResponseHeaderMessage">
    <part name="ResponseHeaderPart" element="msgs:ResponseHeader" />
  </message>

  <portType name="ptMyService">
    <operation name="MyService">
      <input message="tns:mMyService" />
      <output message="tns:mMyServiceResponse" />
    </operation>
    <operation name="GetComponent">
      <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
      <input message="tns:GetComponentRequest" />
      <output message="tns:GetComponentResponse" />
    </operation>
  </portType>

  <binding name="bMyService" type="tns:ptMyService">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document" />
    <operation name="MyService">
      <soap:operation soapAction="MyServiceAction" />
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
        <soap:header message="tns:RequestHeaderMessage" part="RequestHeaderPart" use="literal" />
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
        <soap:header message="tns:ResponseHeaderMessage" part="ResponseHeaderPart" use="literal" />
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="GetComponent">
      <soap:operation soapAction="GetComponent" />
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
        <soap:header message="tns:RequestHeaderMessage" part="RequestHeaderPart" use="literal" />
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
        <soap:header message="tns:ResponseHeaderMessage" part="ResponseHeaderPart" use="literal" />
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>

  <service name="MyServiceService">
    <port name="MyServicePort" binding="tns:bMyService">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:7903/MyService" />
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: Is it this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4214815

Comment: Thanks! Could be. I try this and let u know. If it's that, write answer and get rewarded the bounty.

Comment: yes. it works. u can write answer and I'll accept it for +100 bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your operation methods do *not* have `ReplyAction` set to "*", because WsdlExporter, which generates WSDL metadata, ignores such methods.

```
[OperationContract(ReplyAction="*")]
string SampleMethod(string msg);
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.replyaction%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_2):

> Specifying an asterisk in the service instructs WCF not to add a reply action to the message, which is useful if you are programming against messages directly.